# Advertise and Discover simultaneously with Multipeer

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

Can a device advertise and discover the same service with Multipeer simultaneously? If so, would it find itself?

I am currently trying to get connection between the simulator and an actual device and cannot seem to get them to connect even though they are on the same network and I have called startAdvertisingPeer and startBrowsingForPeers. Thanks.

Code to create MCNearbyService objects in a custom init method which takes in in a target class to notify and send data to. (formatting is a bit broken below)

`- (NMPeerToPeer*)initWithTarget:(id)obj {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        target = obj;
    }`

```
localPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];

MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *advertiser = [[MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID discoveryInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[ReadWriteData readFile:lastUpdatedFilename]] forKey:@"last-updated"] serviceType:XXServiceType];
advertiser.delegate = self;
[advertiser startAdvertisingPeer];
NSLog(@"advertser started");

MCNearbyServiceBrowser* browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:localPeerID serviceType:XXServiceType];
browser.delegate = self;
[browser startBrowsingForPeers];
NSLog(@"browser started");

return self;
```

}`

The discoveryInfo for the advertiser is a a dict of values that the browser will use to determine whether to connect or not.

Currently the advertiser and browser appear to start correctly but none of the delegate methods are called. I have included the delegate ids in the .h file of the class.

Update:
GitHub Gist with multipeer connection class code https://gist.github.com/ansonl/9a98df84942e1f14b2cd.

Comment: Yes, you can advertise and browse at the same time.
No, the device will not discover itself.

Comment: @ChrisH is right about advertising and browsing at the same time. It would help us diagnose your problem if you post the code you are using.

Comment: @ChrisH I have included some of the code. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the discovery info and see if your delegate methods fire. If that works I'll post a full answer.

Comment: @ChrisH, I have tried removed the discovery info and the devices still will not find each other. I have updated my question with the code from the class I have created to handle connections. I think my code may be missing a needed delegate action. Some of the variables like XXServiceType are just constants. 
Gist with code: https://gist.github.com/ansonl/9a98df84942e1f14b2cd